# Relationship tags not updating for import contacts drop down list

Tags: contacts, custom-fields, relationships, civicontact

I have recently changed some of the relationship tags. These new tags come up when I am inputting or updating an individual contact. However, when I do a group upload and go to select the new relationships in the drop down list it has not updated. It does not show the new relationships I have created and it still shows the relationships that I have deleted.

Is there a seperate sync that I am missing? - I haven't been able to find a reason for the issue on the manual at all.

I have also checked that my tags correspond to the correct contact types I am trying to upload.

Comment: Tags and relationships are different things.  It might be better if you edit this question and include a few screenshots showing the problem you're having.

Comment: could it be that the relationships will not show if there are any Contact Types in your set of contacts who do not meet the Relationship requirements